# -bash: icc: command not found in MAC

Tags: c++, bash, macos, installation

I wanted to compile my programs using intel compiler. So I downloaded it from [here](http://registrationcenter-download.intel.com/akdlm/irc_nas/tec/11296/m_ipp_2017.2.163.dmg) and installed in my MAC OS 10.12.2. Then I went to the directory `/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2017.2.163/mac/bin` and then typed

```
./compilervars.sh -arch intel64 -platform mac
```

When I tried icc ipptest.cpp -o ipptest to compile a sample program, I got the error

```
-bash: icc: command not found
```

Googling about it didn't solve the issue. Help me to resolve this issue

Comment: could you possibly need to use `. ./compilervars.sh ...`  or `source ./compilervars.sh ...`?

Comment: @StefanHegny Thanks for reply. But that didn't work. The compilervars.sh file needs parameters.

Comment: you can pass the parameters also if you use `. ./compilervars.sh`...

Comment: @StefanHegny I tried . ./compilervars.sh -arch intel64 -platform mac   and  source ./compilervars.sh -arch intel64 -platform mac. Still the error comes